# Error: Installing Python libraries from the computer

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have windows 10. Python 3.10. And an updated version of pip.

I downloaded some Python libraries to my computer. and every time I try to install them I get the following error. for example:
I try to install **numpy** using the following command:

```
pip install C:\Users\Tania\Downloads\numpy-1.23.1.tar.gz
```

I get this error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Processing c:\users\tania\downloads\numpy-1.23.1.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [8 lines of output]
      Ignoring packaging: markers 'platform_machine == "arm64"' don't match your environment
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001812FF39D80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001812FF39960>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001812FF39B10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001812FF3B880>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001812FF3A440>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed')': /simple/setuptools/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools==59.2.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools==59.2.0
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I also tried to install through the command:

```
pip install numpy
```

And I also got an error.

Comment: Uninstall all, and make a clean new installation of Python or anaconda. Install packages with pip instead of download them and install.

Comment: Or try to change the directory to the package path and then pip install.

Comment: @felixpradoh won't work

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org numpy -vvv
```